# Play 2.6 CORS filter not working

Tags: playframework

Following documentation at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/CorsFilter I have added below configuration in my application.

```
play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.cors.CORSFilter"

play.filters.cors {      
  exposedHeaders = ["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"]
}

GET    /v1/user/:username  controllers.MyController.user(username)
```

I'm using Play 2.6 (scala). I want to keep rest of setting values as default in reference.conf With this configuration, I'm not seeing Access-Control-Allow-Origin header coming from server. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you actually send a CORS request? i.e., a request with CORS headers? If not, play will not add CORS headers to the response to a non-CORS request.

Comment: ^ This comment is the right answer.

Comment: If you're going to take time to contribute to SO, and you know an answer, why not post an example Frederic, Lenin?